# Adding P-Asserted-Identity / P-Preferred-Identity on FreeSwitch

Tags: sip, freeswitch

How can i modify the dial plan / sofia profile to insert the P-Asserted-Identity or the P-Preferred-Identity Headers on Freeswitch?

I have the information in FROM Header and like to anonymize it and provide it in one of the P-Headers.

Answer (score 4):

it's controlled by `sip_cid_type` variable and very easy to find with google :-)

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/sip_cid_type

Comment: I was trying out <param name="caller-id-type" value="pid"/> in the Sofia Profile and ignored the global variable. I shall try it out.