# Adding P-Early-Media on FreeSwitch

Tags: freeswitch

How can i modify the dial plan / sofia profile to insert the P-Early-Media Headers on Freeswitch?

I want to integrate with 3GPP base telco core, so I want to when using [pre-answering](https://developer.signalwire.com/freeswitch/FreeSWITCH-Explained/Modules/mod-dptools/6586998#about) add P-Early-Media header in [183 session in progress](https://developer.signalwire.com/freeswitch/FreeSWITCH-Explained/Codecs-and-Media/Early-Media/vs-183-vs-Early-Media_7143480) to telco can play my error voice into phone.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/75897715/1539100

Comment: I want clear answer like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31153918/1539100